Who is the earliest person to mention Bhagavad gita?
As far as I know, oldest surviving commentary on the Bhagavad Gita is written by Adi Shankaracharya. I would like to know whether any commentaries predate him which are either available or lost and who is the earliest person to mention Bhagavad Gita in any of his/her works?

Partial Answer
Adi Shankara, in his introduction to Bhagavad Gita bhAshya, mentions of several earlier commentators on the Gita.

तदिदं गीताशास्त्रं समस्तवेदार्थसारसङ्ग्रहभूतं दुर्विज्ञेयार्थम् , तदर्थाविष्करणायानेकैर्विवृतपदपदार्थवाक्यार्थन्यायमपि अत्यन्तविरुद्धानेकार्थवत्वेन लौकिकैर्गृह्यमाणमुपलभ्य अहं विवेकतोऽर्थनिर्धारणार्थं सङ्क्षेपतो विवरणं करिष्यामि ॥

Translation 1

This famous Gita- Sastra is an epitome of the essentials of the whole Vedic teaching; and its meaning is very difficult to understand. Though, to afford a clear view of its teaching, it has been explained word by word and sentence by sentence and its import critically examined by several commentators still I have found that to the laity it appears to teach diverse and quite contradictory doctrines. I propose, therefore, to write a brief commentary with a view to determine its precise meaning.

Translation 2

This scripture called the Gita, which is such, is the collection of the quintessence of all the teachings of the Vedas, and its meaning is difficult to understand. Finding that although its words, meaning of words, meaning of sentences, and arguments have been expounded by many for the sake of discovering its import, still because of the multiplicity and extreme contradictoriness of the expositions it is not comprehended by people, | shall explain it briefly with a view to determining its meaning distinctly.

